# How to use Fortran shared library in C program?

Tags: c, fortran, shared-libraries

I have put several subroutines into .f95 file, compiled it with`gfortran -shared -fPIC -o bin/Debug/libpr10.so main.f95`, now I want to use some of subroutines from that library in my C program. How do I do that (syntactically)? Do I have to produce any "headers" in Fortran library where I should declare the subroutines I want to use outside of the library (as I would have to if it was C)?
If I just tell the linker where the library is and try to call any subroutines in `main()` i get an error

**UPDATE** I don't want to mix fortran and C! I just want to use one subroutine from Fortran shared library, even w/o arguments. Despite that I have pointed out a path to the .so library, it's "invisible" for C program! The question is how to tell C program that there actually IS a subroutine that I want to invoke.

If I'm violently mistaken with "mixing" idea, correct me.

Comment: What error do you get?   Just tell the linker where the library is.  You can't have two main programs ... wondering because you called your Fortran file "main.f95".  To mix Fortran and C, I suggest starting by compiling the C with option "-c" to get object files, then compile the Fortran and link all, including the object files, with gfortran.  Once you have that working, you can try complications.

Comment: If you are calling a Fortran subroutine from C, you are mixing the languages.  You have to inform the linker about the library.  It's usually easiest to link with the Fortran compiler in order to bring in the Fortran run-time libraries.  I suggest getting it to work first without the shared library, just object files, then adding that step.  Also, take a look at the tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I don't think that this solution is universal but for Microsoft Visual Studio it should be `__stdcall` before subroutne name, and for gcc it should be a `_` symbol after subroutine name e.g. we want to call subroutine called menu, so we put `menu_();` into main function.

Comment: With the Fortran ISO_C_Binding you can specify the procedure name and bypass the name mangling.